# Proof of an equivalent definition for a continuous mapping in a metric space

Tags: general-topology, continuity

$\underline{Theorem:}$  A mapping $f: (X,d) \to (Y, \rho)$ is continuous if and only if either of the following conditions are satisfied.

$$(a) \  \text{For each set} \ U \ \text{that is open in}\  Y, f^{-1}[U] \ \text{is open in}\ X$$

$$(b) \ \text{For each set} \ K \ \text{that is closed in} \ Y, f^{-1}[K] \text{ is closed in} \ X$$

My proof so far,

Let $f:(X,d) \to (Y, \rho)$ be a continuous mapping.  Thus for any $x_0 \in X$ and for any $\epsilon > 0$ there exists a $\delta > 0$ such that if $x \in X$ and $d(x,x_0) < \delta$ then $\rho(f(x),f(x_0))< \epsilon$.  Now let $U$ be a set in $Y$.  Next what I did was assume that (a) is false and try to show this forces (b) to be true.  So I let $K$ be a closed set in $Y$ and I need to show $f^{-1}[K]$ is open in $X$.

This is where I get stuck and unsure how to proceed, any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: I don't understand. If you assume $f$ to be continuous, then (a) will never be false. Hence if you assume (a) to be false, then any conclusion vacuously follows.

Comment: I thought (a) isn't always true for continuous maps.

Comment: The statement of the theorem is that $f$ is continuous iff (a) holds iff (b) holds.

Comment: Wow.. that helps a lot, thanks!